# Detect session timeout after Response.Redirect?

Tags: asp.net

I am implementing the log-in/log-out functionality on a website. Whenever the user clicks on `Sign out` button (anywhere but at the login page, `Login.aspx`), the following method will execute:

```
protected void SignOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Now, when the redirect happens, I want to do the following in `Login.aspx`:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( Session_has_timed_out ... )
        SessionTimeOutDIV.Text = "Session timed out. Please log in again.";
    else
    {
        // normal logic here ...
    }
}
```

**Q:** How do I check that the session was previously terminated, given that I need to check this (1) after the actual call to `Session.Abandon()` and (2) after I am redirected from where the call to `Session.Abandon()` had happened?

Comment: `Session.Abandon()` raises `session_end` event. Yo can set something there. Also after abandon event all your session variables will be null so you can check that. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: @Ravi A. If I understand correctly, `Session.Abandon()` will destroy all session variables. So technically, there is no difference between calling e.g. `Session['username']` **before** the session is even created and **after** is has been abandoned - in both cases we get `null`. That's a problem, because if I just check `Session['username']` in `Page_Init`, then every time the page is initiated, the condition will resolve to `true`. Whereas I only need it to be true whenever the session is **terminated** (i.e. when the user logged out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's why for authentication it is recommended to rely on cookie and use formsAuth or now ASP.Net Identity. If it was MVC we have TempData but for webforms I don't think there is any such thing. So you can use other state management techniques like query string

```
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?Logout=true");
```

In page_init of Login.aspx

```
    if (Request.QueryString["LogOut"] != null && Request.QueryString["LogOut"] == "true") //do handle exception and casting
    {
        //SessionTimeOutDIV.Text = "Session timed out. Please log in again.";
    }
    else
    {
        // normal logic here ...
    }
```

This is only a hack, hope this helps.

Comment: That's a very smart approach, I wonder how it didn't dawn on me! Thanks!